# windows 8 install package using npm cannot find vcbuild.exe, msbuild.exe failed

Tags: node.js, windows-8, npm

I'm trying to install the dependencies of `tower.js`. What i do is:

```
tower new towerBot
cd towerBot
npm install
```

Got the error :

```
C:\Project\towerBot\node_modules\grunt-contrib\node_modules\grunt-contrib-image
min\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\exec-sync\node_modules\ffi\node_modul
es\ref\build\binding.sln : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ compone
nt "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Micr
osoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe` fail
ed with exit code: 1
```

For the first i even got the 2012 version installed. For the `msbuild.exe`, i have no idea. Can you guys help me? I'm using windows 8 64 bit, `node.js` 32 bit v0.8.20, `node-gyp` v0.8.4, and this `node-gyp` also always error when i try to `configure` it, the error is the same as above. Any thougts?

Comment: VCBuild.exe is old, the last version of Visual Studio that still used it is VS2008.  It says as much in the error message.